# calculating exact probability using eigenvalue and eigenvector

Tags: matrices, algorithms, markov-chains

I have markov chain model of state A and B where \begin{equation} \begin{pmatrix} A & B \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 \\ 1/3 & 2/3 \end{pmatrix} \end{equation} is a probability matrix (i.e. A->A=0.5 and B->A=1/3). After many runs ($\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}) $ the probability of being at status A is 0.4 and at B is 0.6. However I would like to develop a function $f(t)$ to calculate exact probability of being at state A in each run. *(clue: It requires understanding of eigenvalue and convector)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Markov chain with intial state (as a row vector, so evolve on the right) $\pi$ and transition matrix $P$, then the state $k$ time steps later is given by $\pi P^k$.

You can compute $P^k$ in a variety of ways -- induction, eigendecomposition, etc. depending on the $P$.

Comment: thanks, could you solve P^K with eigendecomposition approach?

Comment: If you wanted to. If $A=S \Lambda S^{-1}$ where $S$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of $A$, $\Lambda$ is a matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal, $A^k = S \Lambda^k S^{-1}$ where $\Lambda^k$ is simply a matrix with the corresponding eigenvalues in $\Lambda$ raised to the power $k$.

Comment: considering eigenvalue of 1. Could you show me what is matrix $S$ and $Λ$ ? thanks so much

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B1%2F2,1%2F2%7D,%7B1%2F3,2%2F3%7D%7D